# Android how to set ImageButton accessibility focus

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

I trying to apply accessibility about talkback on my app.

I want to change the focus to a `ImageButton` (custom keypad layout) when the user selects `EditText`.

**here is my code summary.**

```
edittext.setAccessibilityDelegate(new View.AccessibilityDelegate() {
    @Override
    public void sendAccessibilityEvent(View host, int eventType) {
        if (eventType == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED || eventType == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED) {
            btn.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED);
        }
    }   
});
```

I set condition about `TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED` and `TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED` because when user double tap on the `EditText`, a state can be already focused.

but, if eventType is `TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED`, the button not only accessibility focus but also cause button click event.

I want to set just focus.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**
Under `onCreate()`

```
editText.requestFocus();
```

**Option 2** - extension of option 1

```
if(editText.requestFocus()) {
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
}
```

**Option 3** - if both option 1 & 2 not working

```
editText.requestFocus();
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Comment: I don't need to use requestFocus(). EditText's focus will get from the user's double tap gesture. I just want to change accessibility focus to button without button click event.

Comment: I solved this problem using code trick. If `EditText` received `TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED` event, resend `TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED`. `sendAccessibilittyEvent()` method will be called recursively. Then send event to `ImageButton`.
I don't know why dose `ImageButton` work `CLICK`.

Comment: @JinEun.Jeong could you share your code solution with me? Maybe just a snippet from your project through email

Comment: Sorry. I was mistaken about this problem. There is a problem still. but I found a reason why button was clicked. First, It is a device problem on Galaxy Note 4 (Android 6.0). Second, when you touch to click, `onClick` event occur before `ACTION_UP` of touch event. so i processed `if (eventType == `TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED` ...)`. UI focus moved already. so `Button` receive the event of touch `DOWN`, `UP`.